# Javascript script-src makes page load twice?

Tags: javascript, jwt, src

I'm working on a "forgot password" link that runs a function that creates a new `JWT`, then redirects to `reset-password.html` and works properly.
However this page needs a `<script src="updatePassword.js"></script>` for the user to save the new password.
The problem is: the simple presence of the `script src...` on the html page makes the `resetPassword` function to run twice and mess up the token creation.
Console logging shows a proper token on the first run and then: `token: updatePassword.js` followed by `jwt malformed`. If I remove the script from the html page this doesnt happen. How do I fix this?

Here's the code for the forgot password link:

```
module.exports.resetPassword = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
  const {id, token } = req.params
  const user = await User.findById(id)
  console.log('token:', token)

  //check user
  if(id != user._id) {
    res.send('Invalid ID')
    return
  }

  const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET + user.password
  try {
    const payload = jwt.verify(token, secret)
    console.log('works')
    res.render('reset-password.html', {email: user.email, userName: user.userName})

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('doesnt work')
    console.log(error.message)
    res.send(error.message)
  }
})
```

Comment: I think the contents of your client-side `updstePassword.js` would be useful to see.

Comment: I commented everything out from updatePassword.js except for a console.log so I don't think it's related.

Comment: So the contents of `updatePassword.js` is literally `console.log(...)`? No functions, imports etc?

Comment: Yes, and still somehow it makes resetPassword run again and grab updatePassword as the token.

Comment: Fascinating. Alright, my guess is that you've got some JS in the page that is querying elements and hitting the server based on their contents, and somehow the added `<script/>` element has been included in that list. Take a look at which conditions cause the client to send the request.